# Is it possible that 2 hermitian matrices multiplied together to get a anti-hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say $A$ and $B$ are hermitian matrices with complex entries, is it possible that $AB$ is anti-hermitian?

If it's possible, what's the condition on the hermitian matrices?

If it's not possible, how to prove it?

Comment: [This](http://msp.org/pjm/1965/15-4/pjm-v15-n4-p03-s.pdf) is a paper you might be interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The simplest examples are the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). For example, $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & -i\\ i & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}i & 0\\ 0 & -i\end{bmatrix}$$
The condition is $A$, $B$ anticommute. i.e $AB + BA  = 0$.

Comment: May I ask a further question? What's the condition for a hermitian matrix A to have such an anti-commutator B? For example, any odd dimension invertible  matrix A obliviously doesn't have such anti-commutator.

Comment: @phchen For non-trivial example, $A$ need to have a pair of eigenvalues opposite sign to each other. If $A,B$ are hermitian and anticommute, then $A^2, B^2$ will be hermitian and commute. We can simultaneously diagonalize $A^2$ and $B^2$. On any block where $A^2 = a^2 I$, $B^2 = b^2 I$ where $a, b \ne 0$, $A$ cannot proportional to $I$ or $B$ will be forced to $0$. So $A$ has both $a$ and $-a$ as its eigenvalue.